# How to send Android's screen out as a video stream?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I'm now implementing a VNC-like app on Android. I wish to send my Android device's screen out in a video stream so that a PC client can receive and display it in real-time.

I can capture single frame of Android device's screen by using ADB's "framebuffer:" command. However, I have no clue how to make it a stream. Anyone can help?

Or, I may refer to some open source Android VNC server & client's code. However, they are often very complicated so that I will not read it until I have tried all other methods.

Does anyone have some clues? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi,hebothu, I am doing the similar thing. Did you test the frame rate of adb framebuffer? It seems the fps is small. If you need the realtime effect, surfaceflinger needs to be considered